# Change yylex in C++ Flex

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I want to change `yylex` to `alpha_yylex`, that also takes in a vector as an argument.

```cpp
.
.
#define YY_DECL int yyFlexLexer::alpha_yylex(std::vector<alpha_token_t> tokens)
%}
.
.
. in main()
std::vector<alpha_token_t> tokens;
while(lexer->alpha_yylex(tokens) != 0) ;
```

I think i know why this fails, because obviously in the `FlexLexer.h` there is NO `alpha_yylex` , but i don't know how to achieve what i want...

How can I make my own alpha_yylex() or modify the existing one?

Comment: Didn't you intend that prototype to be `yyFlexLexer::alpha_yylex(std::vector<alpha_token_t>& tokens)` (note the **&**)? If so, wouldn't it be sufficient (and maybe even better) to add the vector of tokens as a class data member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that you cannot edit the definition of `yyFlexLexer`, since `FlexLexer.h` is effectively a system-wide header file. But you can certainly subclass it, which will provide most of what you need.

## Subclassing `yyFlexLexer`

Flex allows you to use `%option yyclass` (or the `--yyclass` command-line option) to specify the name of a subclass, which will be used instead of `yyFlexLexer` to define `yylex`. Subclassing `yyFlexLexer` allows you to include your own header which defines your subclass' members and maybe even additional functions, as well as its constructors; in short, if your intention was simply to fill in a `std::vector<alpha_token_t>` with the successive tokens, you could easily do that by defining `AlphaLexer` as a subclass of `yyFlexLexer`, with an instance member called `tokens` (or, perhaps, with accessor functions).

You can also add additional member functions to your new class, which might provide what you need those additional arguments for.

The thing which is not quite so straight-forward, although it could easily be accomplished using the `YY_DECL` macro in the C interface, is to change the name and prototype of the scanning function generated by flex. It can be done (see below) but it is not clear that it is actually supported. In any case, it is possibly less important in the case of C++.

Aside from a small wrinkle created by the curious organization of Flex's C++ classes [Note 1], subclassing the lexer class is simple. You need to derive your class from `yyFlexLexer` [Note 2], which is declared in `FlexLexer.h`, and you need to tell Flex what the name of your class is, either by using `%option yyclass` in your Flex file, or by specifying the name on the command line with `--yyclass`.

`yyFlexLexer` includes the various methods for manipulating input buffers, as well as all the mutable state for the lexical scanner used by the standard skeleton. (Much of this is actually derived from the base class `FlexLexer`.) It also includes a virtual `yylex` method with prototype

```cpp
virtual int yylex();
```

When you subclass `yyFlexLexer`, `yyFlexLexer::yylex()` is defined to signal an error by calling `yyFlexLexer::LexerError(const char*)` and the generated scanner is defined as the override in the class defined as `yyclass`. (If you don't subclass, the generated scanner is `yyFlexLexer::yylex()`.)

The one wrinkle is the way you need to declare your subclass. Normally, you would do that in a header file like this:

#### File: myscanner.h (Don't use this version)

```cpp
#pragma once

// DON'T DO THIS; IT WON'T WORK (flex 2.6)
#include <yyFlexLexer.h>

class MyScanner : public yyFlexLexer {
  // whatever
};
```

You would then `#include "myscanner.h"` in any file which needed to use the scanner, *including the generated scanner itself*.

Unfortunately, that won't work because it will result in `FlexLexer.h` being included twice in the generated scanner; `FlexLexer.h` does not have an include guard in the normal sense of the word because it is designed to be included multiple times in order to support the `prefix` option. So you need to define two header files:

#### File: myscanner-internal.h

```cpp
#pragma once
// This file depends on FlexLexer.h having already been included
// in the translation unit. Don't use it other than in the scanner
// definition.
class MyScanner : public yyFlexLexer {
  // whatever
};
```

#### File: myscanner.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <FlexLexer.h>
#include "myscanner.h"
```

Then you use `#include "myscanner.h"` in every file which needs to know about the scanner *except* the scanner definition itself. In your `myscanner.ll` file, you will `#include "myscanner-internal.h"`, which works because Flex has already included `FlexLexer.h` before it inserts the prologue C++ code from your scanner definition.

## Changing the yylex prototype

You can't really *change* the prototype (or name) of `yylex`, because it is declared in `FlexLexer.h` and, as mentioned above, defined to signal an error. You can, however, redefine `YY_DECL` to create a *new* scanner interface. To do so, you must first `#undef` the existing `YY_DECL` definition, at least in your scanner definition, because a scanner with `%option yyclass="MyScanner" contains` #define YY_DECL int MyScanner::yylex()`. That would make your` myscanner-internal.h` file look like this:

```cpp
#pragma once
// This file depends on FlexLexer.h having already been included
// in the translation unit. Don't use it other than in the scanner
// definition.

#undef YY_DECL
#define YY_DECL int MyScanner::alpha_yylex(std::vector<alpha_token_t>& tokens)

#include <vector>
#include "alpha_token.h"

class MyScanner : public yyFlexLexer {
  public:
    int alpha_yylex(std::vector<alpha_token_t>& tokens);

    // whatever else you need
};
```

The fact that the `MyScanner` object still has a (not very functional) `yylex` method might not be a problem. There are some undocumented interfaces  in `FlexLexer` which call `yylex()`, but those don't matter if you don't use them. (They're not all that useful, anyway.) But you should at least be aware that the interface exists.

In any case, I don't see the point of renaming `yylex` (but perhaps you have a different aesthetic sense). It's already effectively namespaced by being a member of a specific class (`MyScanner`, above), so `yylex` doesn't really create any confusion.

In the particular case of the `std::vector<alpha_token_t>&` argument, it seems to me that a cleaner solution would be to put the reference as a member variable in the `MyScanner` class and set it with the constructor or with an accessor method. Unless you actually use different vectors at different points in the lexical analysis -- not evident in the example code in your question -- there's no point burdening every call site with the need to pass the address of the vector into the `yylex` call. Since lexer actions are compiled inside `yylex`, which is a member function of `MyScanner`, instance variables -- even private instance variables -- are usable in the lexer actions. Of course, that's not the only use case for extra `yylex` arguments, but it's a pretty common one.

---

## Notes

1. "The C++ interface is a mess," according to a comment in the generated code.
2. Using `%option prefix`, you can change `yy` to something else if you want to. This a feature which is supposedly intended to allow you to include multiple lexical scanners in the same project. However, if you're planning on subclassing, the base classes for all these lexical scanners will be identical (other than their names). Thus, there is little or no point having different base classes. Renaming the scanner class using `%option prefix` is less flexible and no more efficient than subclassing, and it creates an additional header complication. (See [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35643608/1566221) for details.) So I'd recommend sticking with subclassing.

Comment: Incredible Answer! Thank you so much, it was a very interesting read. Due to time constraints ,i went with the C method of defining the macro prototype function. It was just so effortless, i just used YY_DECL to put my own c++ function in and it works like a charm! I didn't use any classes or anything.

Comment: `#include "myscanner.h"` in  myscanner.h would be `#include "myscanner-internal.h"` ?

Answer (score -1):

My approach is similar to the previous answer. But i use macro to avoid redefination.

### scanner.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#ifndef FLEX_LEXER
#define FLEX_LEXER
#include <FlexLexer.h>
#endif // FLEX_LEXER

#include <vector>

typedef int alpha_token_t;

#undef YY_DECL
#define YY_DECL int Scanner::alpha_yylex(std::vector<alpha_token_t>& tokens)

class Scanner : public yyFlexLexer {
public:
    int alpha_yylex(std::vector<alpha_token_t>& tokens);
};
```

### lexer.l

```
%{

#define FLEX_LEXER
#include "scanner.h"


#define INT_CAST            1
#define MAIN_CAST           2
#define RETURN_CAST         3
#define CONSTANT_CAST       4
#define IDENTIFIER_CAST     5
#define ASSIGN_CAST         6
#define OPERATOR_CAST       7
#define SEMICOLON_CAST      8
#define LBRACKET_CAST       9
#define RBRACKET_CAST       10
#define LBRACE_CAST         11
#define RBRACE_CAST         12

%}

%option c++
%option noyywrap
%option yyclass="Scanner"


IDENTIFIER      [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
CONSTANT        [1-9][0-9]*|0
OPERATOR        "+"|"-"|"*"|"/"|"%"|"<"|"<="|">"|">="|"=="|"!="|"&"|"|"|"^"

%%

"int"           { yyout << INT_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; tokens.push_back(INT_CAST); }
"main"          { yyout << MAIN_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; tokens.push_back(MAIN_CAST); }
"return"        { yyout << RETURN_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; tokens.push_back(RETURN_CAST); }

{IDENTIFIER}    { yyout << IDENTIFIER_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; }
{CONSTANT}      { yyout << CONSTANT_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; }
{OPERATOR}      { yyout << OPERATOR_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; }
"="             { yyout << ASSIGN_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; }
";"             { yyout << SEMICOLON_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; }
"("             { yyout << LBRACKET_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; }
")"             { yyout << RBRACKET_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; }
"{"             { yyout << LBRACE_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; }
"}"             { yyout << RBRACE_CAST << ' ' << yytext << std::endl; }

[ \t\n]         { /* ignore whitespace */ }

%%
```

### main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "scanner.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <input_file>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream file(argv[1]);

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Scanner scanner;

    scanner.switch_streams(file, std::cout);

    std::vector<alpha_token_t> tokens;
    scanner.alpha_yylex(tokens);

    for (auto token : tokens) {
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn’t allow you to add an argument.

Comment: @user207421
Just like in the high-score answer, using `#undef YY_DECL` and `#define YY_DECL int Scanner::alpha_yylex(std::vector<int> tokens)` will do. I just proposed a way that doesn't require two header files.

Comment: @user207421
Thank you for pointing out the problem. I will modify my answer.